# Unable to upload file in codeigniter text form

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a text form that works and I have a file uploading form that works using the exact example from the [codeigniter docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) but I dont seem to be able to put the two together. I want a form that allows text and file upload. The text should go to the database and the file to storage with filepath saved in the DB.

I tried adding

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to my text form and the file upload form element. The form action is currently the following method (see below). I have tried to add the method from the codeigniter doc to the method below to allow for file upload but unfortunately this does not work. What am I doing wrong? I suspect that I need to call $_file?

```
public function save()
{
    $project_id = $this->input->post('project_id');
    $id = $this->input->post('task_id');

    if($this->input->post('cancel') !== FALSE) {
        if($id)
            redirect('task/view/'.$project_id.'/'.$id);
        else
            redirect('project/tasks/'.$project_id);
    }

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required');
    etc....

    if($this->form_validation->run() === false)  {
        $this->error = true;

        if ($id)
            $this->edit ($project_id, $id);
        else
            if($project_id)
                $this->add ($project_id);
            else
                redirect('dashboard');

        return;
    }

    $this->load->model('task_model');

    $sql_data = array(
        'project_id'  => $project_id,
        etc...
    );
    if ($id)
        $this->task_model->update($this->input->post('project_id'), $id, $sql_data);
    else
        $id = $this->task_model->create($sql_data);

    //add in upload function here
    $config['upload_path'] = './upload/cell/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|tif';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';
    $config['max_width']  = '2024';
    $config['max_height']  = '1768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_forms', $error);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    }
            // end of added uploader code

    redirect('project/tasks/'.$this->input->post('project_id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the field name

```
 $this->upload->do_upload('upload');
```

instead of

```
$this->upload->do_upload();
```

Where in your HTML the field may be

```
<input type="file" name="upload"/>
```

AS per Codeignitor documentation :

```
If you would like to set your own field name simply pass its 
value to the do_upload function
```

Also make sure that your upload path is valid and is writable

See more info [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I have not changed any of the defaults. I am using `<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />` and I know the file path works because it works when I use it with the codeigniter example.

Comment: Not sure what happened but I was messing around with the code, broke everything and reverted to this and now it works???